# How can I enforce uniqueness for a `set` of property values in a Schema?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am messing around with MongooseJS and trying to create a friend request where I store a `to` and `from` key in MongoDB which are the userId's of the sender and receiver. I want to prevent duplicate requests from the same sender to the same receiver.

Here is my Schema:

```
import { model, Schema, Document } from 'mongoose';
import { FriendRequestInterface } from '@interfaces/friendrequest.interface';
import { FriendRequestStatus } from '@/enums/enumFriendRequest';

const friendRequestSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  to: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    // unique: true,
  },
  from: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    // unique: true,
  },
  message: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    enum: FriendRequestStatus,
    required: true,
  },
});

friendRequestSchema.index({ to: 1, from: 1 }, { unique: true });
const friendRequestModel = model<FriendRequestInterface & Document>('FriendRequest', friendRequestSchema);
export default friendRequestModel;
```

What I POST:

```
{
    "to": "636acf77378903f78b388339",
    "from": "636acf83378903f78b38833f",
    "message": "Hello, I want to be your friend.",
    "status": "pending"
}
```

POSTMAN ERROR:

```
{
    "message": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: db_dev.friendrequests index: from_1 dup key: { from: \"636acf83378903f78b38833f\" }"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my issue was that I still had indexes set inside my collection in MongoDB which were interfering. I cleared all my indexes I made whilst messing around and added the index (compounding) this way:

`friendRequestSchema.index({ to: 1, from: 1 }, { unique: true, sparse: true });`

[image: Where I removed my indexes and added my current one:]